# How to change 00YY year format to 2022 in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Snowflake csv upload turned the date format into "0022-10-02". Is there a best way to change the "0022" format to "2022" format as `NEW_DATE` shows?

| ORDER_DATE | NEW_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 0022-10-02 | 2022-10-02 |
| 0022-10-02 | 2022-10-03 |

I've tried:

```
df["ORDER_DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["ORDER_DATE"], format='%YYYY%mm%dd', errors='ignore')
def swap(x): return re.sub("^00", "20", x) if type(x) is str else x
df.applymap(swap)
print(df)
```

This still shows "0022" in the `ORDER_DATE` column.

I've also tried:

```
df["ORDER_DATE"] = pd.DataFrame({"ORDER_DATE": ["10-02-22", "10-02-22"] })
df.apply(lambda x:x.replace("^00", "20", regex=True))
print(df)
```

Output changes the dates in the `ORDER_DATE` column but it's not ideal, because I'd like to be able to automate the date conversion process from Snowflake.

Comment: If there's a CSV file involved, maybe it would be better to fix the part that loads it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things that need fixing. First, it's best to fix the dates before trying to convert them. Second, `df.applymap()` returns a modified DataFrame, and you aren't saving the result. Third, the format string for the date isn't quite right, but you can actually let `to_datetime()` figure it out with the `yearfirst=True` argument.

This should work to create a `NEW_DATE` column with a corrected date:

```
def swap(x): return re.sub("^00", "20", x) if type(x) is str else x
df['NEW_DATE'] = df['ORDER_DATE'].apply(swap)
df['NEW_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['NEW_DATE'], yearfirst=True)
```

As an example to show that the new column has the correct values and types:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"ORDER_DATE": ["0022-10-02", "0022-11-03"]})
>>> df
   ORDER_DATE
0  0022-10-02
1  0022-11-03
>>> df.dtypes
ORDER_DATE    object
dtype: object

>>> df['NEW_DATE'] = df['ORDER_DATE'].apply(swap)
>>> df['NEW_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['NEW_DATE'], yearfirst=True)
>>> df
   ORDER_DATE   NEW_DATE
0  0022-10-02 2022-10-02
1  0022-11-03 2022-11-03
>>> df.dtypes
ORDER_DATE            object
NEW_DATE      datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried your code and received this error:
`pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 22-10-02 00:00:00`

Comment: @mikestacker487: Do you have the correct `swap()` function? It looks like your years are simply getting the leading `00` removed. It considers year `22` out of bounds.

Comment: thank you. It works now. Looks like I needed to correct the `swap()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `str.replace`

```py
df['NEW_DATE'] = df['ORDER_DATE'].str.replace(r'^(00)(22.*)$', r'20\2', regex=True)
```

```
print(df)

   ORDER_DATE    NEW_DATE
0  0022-10-02  2022-10-02
1  0022-10-02  2022-10-02
```